# IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-gradle-plugin

I've been getting this fatal error today after changing some gradle dependences. Even though I tried to revert the gradle dependences back to the original I'm still getting the error on this line:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() // IllegalStateException
```

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.MainActivity}: 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:186)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:70)
    at com.app.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:43)
```

gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {

// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:17.0.0'

}
```

gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

According to multiple answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735712/6733153) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735712/6733153) the problem is related to the google-services dependency - which i have changed to the recommended version `4.2.0` - but I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea how I can fix it?

Edit:

This is a duplicate because the proposed answer `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` did not solve the issue.

EDIT 2: There is no error on my emulator, only my device

Comment: I also tried adding `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` in my `onCreate()` and Application class before accessing the Firebase instance but I recieved the same error. @ManojPerumarath

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting up Firebase using Android Studio(3.5) assistant.

Here is the recommended dependencies they showed me to inject

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

In app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.4'
```

> You don't need to add all these dependencies, just add the required ones only. Otherwise the APK will get larger.

Comment: I have tried `4.2.0` and it still doesn't work. And I use all of those firebase services you listed for my app, so I need to include all those dependencies.

Comment: @Zorgan did you try the dependency versions 16.0 something on all

Comment: Yes I tried your dependencies and they couldn't work because I got this error: `In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[17.0.
4]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.`

`Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[17.0.4], but fire
base-iid version was 19.0.0. The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.`

Comment: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.4`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when the **Package name** in the **Manifest** was different from **"package_name"** in **google-services.json**.

After i fixed the package name, I had to uninstall the application and clean up the build.

In Xamarine: You don't need to call

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context);
```

You can directly call

```
await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic(topic);
```

or

```
Java.Lang.Object token = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
```

It works like a charm. :-)